# Does anyone know an API for decoding strings like cron does in C?

Tags: c

I'm a newbie in C and i want to read a file which lines are like 30 7 * * 14-15 and parse to date structures.
So i would really use your help to find an API or an algorithm to do it.

Comment: The "algorithm" is essentially "read each line column by column". You'll learn it from any introductory book. (And do decide on a language.)

Comment: it is not only read line by line, it need to parse values and create date and time event notifier.

Comment: This website is for asking people to help you get past problems you're having writing code, not a place to ask them to write code for you when you haven't had a go and got stuck, nor a place to ask for suggestions about libraries or APIs.  That's all made clear in the site's introductory documentation, which you should read.  If you'd at least googled and experimented and presented an effort to open and read a file, parse different data types etc. - we'd have a starting point from which to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to read sources, for example concerning freebsd, fetch os sources (if not aredy done as part of standart os upgrade procedure) , find cron, see sources, take what you need. It is not so unreal as seems.

Sources well documented at comments:
https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/usr.sbin/cron/cron/database.c?revision=225736&view=markup

UPD: link suggested in comment by @PeterT (more exactly for parsing entry):
https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/usr.sbin/cron/lib/entry.c?view=markup#l88

Comment: it will be good practice to get near to os and software development process

Comment: he's clearly interested in the parsing, so shouldn't you link to it: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/usr.sbin/cron/lib/entry.c?view=markup#l88

Comment: Thanks, added to answer